# I want notification to continue to show until the user taps on it (Android)

Tags: android, android-notifications

Currently my notification shows at the top of the screen but then disapears after a bit without any sort of interaction. The notification is an incoming call and so I want it to be visible until the user interacts with it. What changes should I make?

```
    private void showNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
        try{
            // Create an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,remoteMessage);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_name)
                    .setContentTitle("Incoming Video Conference Call")
                    .setContentText("From Demo Doctor")
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)                  
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


            // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
            notificationId++;
            Log.d(TAG, "NotificationId: " + notificationId);
            //https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive
            // Provide a unique integer for the "notificationId" of each notification.
            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

// notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
            notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }


    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but Android does not support this on newer OS versions. Previously, you would launch an activity from the background (rather than show a notification), but this ability was abused, particularly in ways that resulted in security problems. A heads-up notification -- what you get from `PRIORITY_HIGH` -- is pretty much as good as it gets. If the screen is off, as we discussed previously, a full-screen `Intent` should be able to give you what you want. But if the user is actively using their device, it is their right to ignore your notification.

Comment: Another possibly-temporary solution is to request the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission ("Draw over other apps"), and then you can display arbitrary floating content over everything. Facebook's "chat heads" were an early adopter of this. However, this too has been abused, and there are signs that it will be going away in the future. Plus, some people, such as myself, refuse to grant most apps this permission, and for those cases, you would need to do something else anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Using `.setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent,true);` instead of `.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);` actually shows the notification for long time.